# How to remove duplicate records in a file when the first line of each record is the same using perl?

Tags: perl

Each record in a file is separated by **Data** and set the input record separator to **Data**

For example, a file called duplicates.txt have the following records

```
 __Data__
 cccccccc
 slslslsl
 dkdkdkdk

 __Data__
 cccccccc
 rrrrrrrr
 dkdkdkdk
```

Now I would like to remove duplicate records from this file by comparing the first line of each record... can someone give me an ideal how to get started on this with an example using perl..

I know at least I have to set the input record separator to the following:

```
   $/="__Data__\n";
```

Next, I open and read in the record's file.

```
    open my $read_line,"<:encoding(utf-8)","/home/perl/duplicate_records.txt";
    while(<$read_line>)
    {
      # lost at this point but will try to get the first line after the input record separter
      if(/__Data__\n(.*)/)
      {
          my $first_line = $1;
          # not sure what to do next
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *remove duplicates*? Either entries or one of them? In case of only one, the first one or the second one?

Comment: I mention to how to remove duplicate records by comparing the first line of each record. So in other words, if the first line of each record is the same, that counts as a duplicate record and needs to be removed.

Answer (score 2):

`__Data__\n` are last chars in `$_` so you can't match anything after them.

```
my %seen;
while (<$read_line>)
{
  if (/(.*)/ and !$seen{$1}++)
  {
      print "$_ [has unique first line]\n";
  }
}
```